# Unable to convert string variable to factor in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to work with a new dataset and running some preliminary code. I was able to import the csv file into R using `read_csv` no problem. However, for some of the columns, when I run `typeof()` I get Null and also I'm unable to convert them to factor variables using two different methods. Below are my code and a screenshot:

```
library(readr)
dataset = read_csv("breast_cancer.csv")
head(dataset)
```

[image: Runs fine so far]

Runs fine so far.

```
is.factor(dataset$cancer_type)
typeof(dataset$cancer_type) # This returns NULL when this should be string or char.
```

[image]

```
dataset$cancer_type = as.factor(dataset$cancer_type)
```

Running this code above gives this error:

`Error: Assigned data as.factor(dataset$cancer_type) must be compatible with existing data. x Existing data has 2509 rows. x Assigned data has 0 rows. i Only vectors of size 1 are recycled.`

```
dataset[, 'cancer_type'] = as.factor(dataset[, 'cancer_type'])
```

Running this above gives error:

`Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist. x Column cancer_type doesn't exist.`

This is happening to a couple other variables in this dataset as well. What am I missing? Please advise.

The link to the dataset is here:

https://www.kaggle.com/gunesevitan/breast-cancer-metabric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few basics -

Read the data.

```
dataset = readr::read_csv("Breast Cancer METABRIC.csv")
```

Get the names of the column in the dataset -

```
names(dataset)

# [1] "Patient ID"                     "Age at Diagnosis"               "Type of Breast Surgery"        
# [4] "Cancer Type"                    "Cancer Type Detailed"           "Cellularity"                   
# [7] "Chemotherapy"                   "Pam50 + Claudin-low subtype"    "Cohort"                        
#[10] "ER status measured by IHC"      "ER Status"                      "Neoplasm Histologic Grade"     
#[13] "HER2 status measured by SNP6"   "HER2 Status"                    "Tumor Other Histologic Subtype"
#[16] "Hormone Therapy"                "Inferred Menopausal State"      "Integrative Cluster"           
#[19] "Primary Tumor Laterality"       "Lymph nodes examined positive"  "Mutation Count"                
#[22] "Nottingham prognostic index"    "Oncotree Code"                  "Overall Survival (Months)"     
#[25] "Overall Survival Status"        "PR Status"                      "Radio Therapy"                 
#[28] "Relapse Free Status (Months)"   "Relapse Free Status"            "Sex"                           
#[31] "3-Gene classifier subtype"      "Tumor Size"                     "Tumor Stage"                   
#[34] "Patient's Vital Status"
```

Note that your column names have spaces in them. These are non-standard column names. R does not like to have column names with spaces in them (If you use `read.csv` it will actually remove these spaces from the column names and replace it with dot).

If you want to select a column with `$` sign we usually use `dataframe_name$column_name` (eg - `mtcars$mpg`) but since you have a column with spaces in them you need to add backticks to them to select a column.

```
dataset$`Cancer Type`

#[1] "Breast Cancer"  "Breast Cancer"  "Breast Cancer"  "Breast Cancer"  "Breast Cancer" 
#[6] "Breast Cancer"  "Breast Cancer"  "Breast Cancer"  "Breast Cancer"  "Breast Cancer" 
#[11] "Breast Cancer"  "Breast Cancer"  "Breast Cancer"  "Breast Cancer"  "Breast Cancer" 
#[16] "Breast Cancer"  "Breast Cancer"  "Breast Cancer"  "Breast Cancer"  "Breast Cancer" 
#....
#....
```

To check the class of the column use `class` and not `typeof`.

```
class(dataset$`Cancer Type`)
#[1] "character"
```

Check if the variable is factor.

```
is.factor(dataset$`Cancer Type`)
#[1] FALSE
```

Now, convert the variable to factor

```
dataset$`Cancer Type` <- factor(dataset$`Cancer Type`)

#Check class
class(dataset$`Cancer Type`)
#[1] "factor"

#Use is.factor to check. 
is.factor(dataset$`Cancer Type`)
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
as.factor(`Cancer Type`)
```

with space and capital letters

Comment: What do you mean? Not even put dataset in front?

Comment: in your data `cancer_type` column not exist... but `Cancer Type` it does. that's probably the only issue

Comment: So I did this. `dataset[, 'Cancer Type'] = as.factor(dataset[, 'Cancer Type'])`
and when I check with `is.factor` it still shows FALSE. Also that may be the name of the column but if I want to use the $ sign shouldn't it still be `cancer_type` according to the original dataset source?

Comment: unfortunately not. you should try `is.factor(dataset$'Cancer Type')` after encode as a factor. In future use `janitor` package for examining and cleaning dirty data (i.e. colnames)

Comment: I got it, this worked. Is there any way to find the name of the column without the quotations? In the original source it's given to be `cancer_type`. Somehow it got renamed to `Cancer Type`

Comment: its not renamed - that name is in the original file. unfortunately if names contains spaces, its nessesery to use quote or gravis. like above; use `janitor` to change names to whatever are convenient for you